# Remove sidebar from homepage (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My sidebar is showing at the bottom right of my homepage: https://www.moneynest.co.uk

Any idea how I can hide it from here?

It seems to have a made an appearance following the recent Wordpress core upgrade.

The html of the sidebar appearing is as follows:

```
<aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" id="genesis-sidebar-primary">
    <!-- CONTENT OF THE SIDEBAR -->
</aside>
```

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Depends on your theme, but maybe try to login as an admin and go to Appearance->Widgets and remove the Sidebar Widget from that screen?

Comment: Thanks it's a custom theme within the Genesis framework. If I remove the widget it will drop it from /blog etc where I would like to keep it.

Comment: The easiest and quickest way to do this is to add some css to hide the . widget_recent_entries class on the homepage only.  so something like: body.home .sidebar .widget_recent_entries { display: none; }

Comment: I have added relevant code snippets to your answer but please remember to do that yourself the next time you post a question here. Without relevant codes, your question will be flagged and likely to be closed as the issues raised becomes irrelevant once your external links that you provided expire or stop working thus rendering the thread useless for people who might have the same issue as you do in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, so add the classes? I'm always unsure what I need to add/not add as I seem to get downvoted either way! Your solution worked well.

Comment: Thanks too @Moose also!

Comment: No, you don't have to add any classes. Wordpress appends the classes by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add page-specified css by targeting the custom body classes appended by wordpress like this:

```
body.home .sidebar-primary {
    display: none;
}
```